# Force every external USB storage device (USB HDD, USB flash drives of any brand, etc.) to be assigned the same letter G:

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, plug-and-play

I know the "Disk management" (diskmgmt.msc) way to assign a driver letter such as `G:` to a (currently physically present) specific disk or device. But here my question is a little bit different.

How to force every USB external storage device (USB HDD, USB flash drives of any brand, etc.) to be assigned the same letter `G:`? Always, with no exception, for all devices that will be inserted in the future.

Note: only one USB port is available on this kiosk embedded computer, and if someone plugs a USB hub, then it's ok if it is G:, H:, I:, since I won't supported the other devices.

Comment: You can't assign a drive letter to a specific USB port: a port is just a BUS address. Your best bet is probably to map dirve letters up to F: to local folders or network drives. Then the next device which gets connected will be assigned the letter G: by the mount manager. This could break at some point, though.  If I'll have the time, I'll try to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a third-party tool :
[USB Drive Letter Manager (USBDLM)](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html)
($15, but the trial is fully functional and never expires for
home and educational users).

USBDLM is configured thru a text file, `USBDLM.INI`, residing in the
same folder as `USBDLM.EXE`.

The configuration file can limit the number of default letters for
new USB drives via a directive such as:

```
[DriveLetters]
Letters=G
```

I have not installed this product, so cannot test whether it works
as you intend.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this directly from the registry or another way without 3rd party tool? (I guess this tool does this by modifying the registry too)

Comment: I don't think it modifies the registry. Its system service needs to be running in order for this to work - registry changes don't need it.